# Retrieving images from a folder and displaying it in the figure window of matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, matlab-figure

I am working on content based image retrieval.

I have found the images which are more similar to the query image and stored the result in a matrix as follows

q =

```
     100       -1293
      50       -1237
       8       -1075
     102       -1024
     141        -951
```

100th image is more similar, 50th image is the second image that is more similar.

All these images are in a folder. How to retrieve these images inside matlab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 folder = 'c:\images'; % folder were all images are
 img_names; % a cell array where each cell is the name of the image, e.g. img_names{3} is 'photo005.png'
 n = size(q,1); % number of images to be displayed
 w = max(1, floor( sqrt(n) ) );
 h = ceil( n / w );
 figure('Name','Query results');
 for ii = 1:n,
     subplot(w,h,ii);
     img = imread( fullfile( folder, img_names{ q(ii,1) } ) );
     imshow( img );
     title( sprintf( '(%d) img %d score %d', ii, q(ii,1), q(ii,2) ) );
 end
```

Comment: I am getting an error "undefined function or variable" for using img_names @Shai

Comment: @user2031552 - you'll have to define this variable yourself, filling it with the file names of all the images according to their order.

Comment: @Mrk `q` is the query result as you defined it in your question. it is `n` by 2 matrix with first column the image index and the second one is the score.

Comment: Yes @Shai :-). I forgot the variable in the question (lol). Now I got it right. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Mrk - glad I could be of assistance!